# why does this make my display go mad? (but only sometimes)

Tags: c, embedded, display

[image]

[image]

it seems this code make my display go crazy sometimes (but only sometimes). But when I remove **`dat=~dat;`** it seems to work fine.
why?

what I am trying to do here is just make the ascii letters be the oposite: so for example:

**11001000** will be:
**00110111**
or

**10101111** would be:
**01010000**

the reason for doing this is that i want to have one row (the active row) in the diplay window with black on white pixels instead of opostie like the rest of the display window.

Is there some other way I could do this? (invert the numbers)

FYI: I am programing in C. Atmel studio. atmega 4809, SSD1305z display, SPI-simular interface.

```
   void displayinvertedString(char str[], uint8_t ypos,uint8_t xpos)
   {
       Set_Page_Address(ypos);
       Set_Column_Address(xpos);

       int len = strlen(str);
       uint8_t dat;
       int temp;    

       for (int e=0; e<len; e++)
       {
           dat = 0xff;
           Write_Data(dat);  //to get an extra space between the
                             // numbers/letters for 
                             //making it easier to read the text on the display

           temp = str[e];
           temp=temp-0x20; // As the lookup table starts from Space(0x20)
            for (int w=0; w<5; w++)
            {
                dat= OledFontTable[temp][w]; // Get the data to be displayed for LookUptable

                dat =~ dat;
                Write_Data(dat);
            }
        }
    }


----------


static uint8_t OledFontTable[][FONT_SIZE]={   

    //static uint8_t OledFontTable[] = {
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,   // space
    0x00, 0x00, 0x2f, 0x00, 0x00,   // !
    0x00, 0x07, 0x00, 0x07, 0x00,   // "
    0x14, 0x7f, 0x14, 0x7f, 0x14,   // #
    0x24, 0x2a, 0x7f, 0x2a, 0x12,   // $

    0x23, 0x13, 0x08, 0x64, 0x62,   // %
    0x36, 0x49, 0x55, 0x22, 0x50,   // &
```

ETC. Etc.

just more raw pixel data here. this part ends like this:

```
0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00,   // |
0x00, 0x82, 0x7C, 0x10, 0x00,   // }
0x00, 0x06, 0x09, 0x09, 0x06    // ~ (Degrees)

};
```

---

```
void Write_Data(unsigned char Data)
{
PORTA.OUTCLR    = PIN7_bm; //cs
PORTB.OUTSET    = PIN2_bm; //dc
Write_Command(Data); //
}

void Write_Command(unsigned char data)
{
    SPI0.DATA = data;       // copy data to DATA register
    while ((SPI0.INTFLAGS & SPI_RXCIF_bm) == 0) ; //wait
}
```

I have asked a bit about this before. but i thought i would look "cleaner" with a new tread since info was missing from the last one.

Comment: What do you mean by "my display go crazy"? What happens?

Comment: `ETC.`? We can't see the behavior (or the desired behavior) if you don't include your whole program.

Comment: _...since info was missing from the last one._  There appears to be info missing from this one too.  Please edit to provide a [mcve].

Comment: The issue is likely to be in whatever `Write_Data()` does perhaps.  Is it non-deterministic, or does it happen with specific characters or string lengths perhaps?

Comment: `temp=temp-0x20;` and `dat= OledFontTable[temp][w];` This is very wrong because of you dont know temp is in range of `OledFontTable` and is positive or negative. `temp` should be `size_t` type. First of all debug `temp` value.

Comment: @IgorGalczak What makes you think that? The OP wrote the code and the font table so why wouldn't they be aware? Seems like they are discarding the non-printable part of the ASCII table in flash, makes perfect sense. `temp` should _not_ be size_t because this is a 8 bit MCU from the Jurassic period and not a PC.

Comment: @Lundin Because this function is extern so i can call with `str = {-30, 20, 10, 50, 'c', '\t', '\0'};` Everywhere where we use variable as size of array this should be unsigned - best `size_t` and check is in range of array. In embedded we dont have segm. falout so this is important.

Comment: @IgorGalczak The solution: don't call it with a super-weird non-string. Your bug is on the caller-side for doing stupid things.

Comment: I added the code for sending the data to the display. the part where i wrote etc is just more of raw pixel information.

Comment: also added some images. it only happens sometimes. it´s a menu so the text is static. and it do not happen it seems when I don´t invert the text in the menu (if i remove   dat =~ dat;)  any ideas to what i should do?

Comment: I do get a warning that maybe can help: 
Warning  missing braces around initializer.  it is pointing to OledFontTable.. can this be something related?..

Comment: The warning is not related, it just wants you do group the initializers of the 2D array in groups of {}. It is a style issue. Looking at your screen shots, this could be anything including EMI noise on the lines. For example accidentally getting a data transfer corrupted so that the display thinks it is a control frame. Or if you are using DMA, some re-entrancy bug maybe.

Comment: Is the write issued just after power on ? it seems the display got commands to a wrong register. Maybe add some delay before the first write (20-200ms). Also try adding somme delay (0.1-1ms) between each `Write_Command` in the loop. The display may have detected some ghost command between your commands because the time between two sleeps is near or less to SPI clock.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out I needed to toggle the chip select (CS) so the clock did not get out of sync with time.
The clock sync drifted with time.

It was going crazy faster for the non inverted data for some reason. But with the normal data it happend after some time also.

Thank you for the answers.